# Deploy webpack application on WebStorm

Tags: webpack, deployment, webstorm

I'm using webpack with WebStorm and I want to deploy the generated `dist` folder to my remote server.

I've configured the FTP connection, but I can't select the `dist` folder in the "Local path" field because It gives the error "Local path `project\dist` is out of project.

How can I configure WebStorm?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known usability issue: webpack destination directory is auto-excluded from indexing for better performance, and excluded folders can't be deployed, as they are considered to be external. Related youtrack tickets: [WI-21013](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21013), [WI-7367](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7367).

Removing webpack config reference from **Preferences / Languages / Javascript / Webpack** should help

Comment: I've done that, and I also removed `dist` from  excluded folders, but I still can't set the directory for deployment. It forces me to add both `project\dist` and `project` in "Mapping" section.